# Cleaning a Percentage variable

Tags: php, regex

I have an input field where users are entering a percentage. When they enter something like `41.2` it's fine, but if they enter `41.` PHP gives me problems when I'm using that number in a calculation. Sometimes they're also putting a percent sign (`%`), which is bad. Here is what I've tried:

```
$pctcomplete = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$_POST["pctcomplete"]);
```

But if I put in `41.2` it comes out as `412`.

Is there a way to keep the decimal point if it's anywhere but the last character in an input field?

Comment: Why not do `rtrim($_POST['pctcomplete'], '.')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`floatval()`](http://www.php.net/floatval) to extract the value. And on a side note also check if the POST variable is given or not.

```
$pctcomplete = isset($_POST["pctcomplete"]) ? floatval($_POST["pctcomplete"]) : 0;
```